# "Time Conversion" Python implementation

Tags: python, object-oriented, programming-challenge, python-2.x

Problem Statement

> You are given time in AM/PM format. Convert this into a 24 hour format.
>
> Note Midnight is \$ 12:00:00AM \$ or \$ 00:00:00 \$ and 12 Noon is \$ 12:00:00PM. \$

Input Format

> Input consists of time in the AM/PM format i.e. hh:mm:ssAM or hh:mm:ssPM 
>   where 
>   \$ 01 \le hh \le 12 \$,
>   \$ 00 \le mm \le 59 \$,
>   \$ 00 \le ss \le 59 \$

Output Format

> You need to print the time in 24 hour format i.e. hh:mm:ss 
>   where
>
> \$ 00 \le hh \le 23 \$,
>   \$ 00 \le mm \le 59 \$,
>   \$ 00 \le ss \le 59 \$

Sample Input

> \$ 07:05:45PM \$

Sample Output

> \$ 19:05:45 \$

Solution

```
class AbsTime(object):

    def __init__(self, hh, mm=0, ss=0, pm=False):
        self.hh = hh
        self.mm = mm
        self.ss = ss
        self.pm = pm

    def add(self, time):
        self.hh += time.hh
        self.mm += time.mm
        self.ss += time.ss

        if self.ss >= 60:
            self.ss -= 1
            self.mm += 1
        if self.mm >= 60:
            self.mm -= 1
            self.hh = self.hh % 24
        return self

    def midnight(self):
        return not self.pm and str(self) in ['00:00:00', '12:00:00']

    def noon(self):
        return self.pm and str(self) == '12:00:00'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}".format(self.hh, self.mm, self.ss)

    def get(self):
        if self.midnight():
            return AbsTime(0)
        if self.noon():
            return AbsTime(12)
        if self.pm:
            if self.hh == 12:
                hh = self.hh
            else:
                hh = self.hh + 12
            return AbsTime(hh, self.mm, self.ss)
        else:
            return AbsTime(self.hh % 12, self.mm, self.ss)

    @classmethod
    def create_from_string(cls, time):
        pm = True if time[-2:] == 'PM' else False      
        hh, mm, ss = map(int, time[:-2].split(':'))
        return cls(hh, mm, ss, pm)


def main(time):
    if time == '00:00:00':
        return time

    abstime = AbsTime.create_from_string(time)
    return abstime.get()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TIME = raw_input().strip()
    print main(TIME)
    #print main('00:00:00')   #00:00:00
    #print main('12:00:00PM') #12:00:00
    #print main('12:00:00AM') #00:00:00
    #print main('02:00:00PM') #14:00:00
    #print main('02:00:00AM') #02:00:00 
    #print main('11:59:00AM') #11:59:00
    #print main('12:59:00PM') #12:59:00
    #print main('01:00:00PM') #13:00:00
    #print main('11:59:59PM') #23:59:59
    #print main('12:59:59AM') #00:59:59
```

It really took me a while to do this simple solution, its fast when we do just structural programming but once I thought to step into **OOP** world things really got confusing. How can I improve this design?

Answer (score 1):

Using an internal representation of time that is as simple as possible would simplify your work. For example, using internally seconds since midnight, the `add` method could become

```
def add(self, other):
    self.seconds = (self.seconds + other.seconds) % SECONDS_IN_DAY
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) and [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) from the `time` module to do this:

```
current_time = time.strptime(time_string, "%I:%M:%S%p")
time_formatted = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", current_time)
```

Comment: Yes, but I would like to know how can I have a better `OO` design.